# in python, compare two array in element and change the lower value to zero

Tags: python, compare

now we have two arrays

```
a = [[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.],[9.,8.,7.,6.,5.,4.,3.,2.,1.]]

b = [[2.,2.,1.,2.,0.,2.,1.,2.,0.],[2.,2.,1.,2.,0.,2.,1.,2.,0.]]
```

Is there any fast way to achieve the following function: 
compare these two arrays by element, and change the array a[] in the following rule:

```
if a[i,j] > b[i,j]: 

    a[i,j] = a[i,j] 

else   

a[i,j] = 0
```

I know that a loop can do it, but I am wondering if there is any other faster way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.],[9.,8.,7.,6.,5.,4.,3.,2.,1.]])
b = np.array([[2.,2.,1.,2.,0.,2.,1.,2.,0.],[2.,2.,1.,2.,0.,2.,1.,2.,0.]])

gr = np.greater(a,b)
a = np.multiply(a,gr)
```

The gr and a arrays become:

```
[[False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True False  True]]

array([[ 0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 9.,  8.,  7.,  6.,  5.,  4.,  3.,  0.,  1.]])
```